# Vim - Activiting HTML snippets on PHP files

Tags: vim, snipmate

I am using vim and snipMate, many times I need to name the HTML files to PHP, just because of 1 or 2 lines of code.

I every time I create a PHP file vim takes it as PHP file and so the HTML snippets are not available, thus have to activate the HTML snippets manually with the command.

```
set ft=php.html
```

I intend to activate it automatically in this this line on my vimrc

```
autocmd BufREad, BufNewFile *.php set ft=php.html
```

Is this correct? I am missing anything or is something wrong?

Answer (score 11):

You will need to make it two separate directives.

```
au BufRead *.php set ft=php.html
au BufNewFile *.php set ft=php.html
```

Comment: I think you can do that in single line, just remove the space between `BufRead` and `BufNewFile`.

Answer (score 4):

You have an uppercase E in your example.
The following should work on one line:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.php set ft=php.html
```

Comment: I think the space after the comma might have been the real problem.