# vim - using snipmate and ragtag together

Tags: php, html, vim, snipmate

I am trying to switch to vim for all my editing and trying out the plugins. I have been using snipmate and ragtag and like them both. Now I am coding PHP with HTML in it and I saw this question to get snipmate to work with snippets for the two file types here: [Vim - Activiting HTML snippets on PHP files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008575/vim-activiting-html-snippets-on-php-files) .

This works well, I can get snippets for both PHP and HTML, but ragtag is no longer introducing PHP `<?php ... ?>` blocks, it's introducing `<% ... %>`. Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that Ragtag doesn't understand multiple filetypes. Does it work when you `:set ft=php` or `:set ft=html.php` ?

I've never used ragtag, but since you are using Snipmate too why don't you just type `php<Tab>`?

It's certainly a lot easier to remember and more "mnemonic" than `<C-X>_` (if I read the doc well).

**-- EDIT --**

It appears a check is made on `ft` (filetype) [at line 71](https://github.com/tpope/vim-ragtag/blob/master/plugin/ragtag.vim#L71) but it accepts only `"php"` as value, since you have `set ft=php.html` ragtag should accept `"php.html"` as well.

I think changing this line from

```
if &ft == "php"
```

to

```
if &ft == "php" || &ft == "php.html"
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works quite well. The reason I'm not using snipmate for the php tag is that i'm using a lot of inline `<?php echo $something; ?>` statements and the snipmate makes multiline indented tags.

Comment: You could add a custom "`ph`" snippet that expands to `<?php [cursor] ?>`.