# Vim cannot recognise HTML5 tags in PHP

Tags: php, html, vim

I'd like to use HTML5 Tags in PHP, but Vim can't recognize them.
I have installed this plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3236
But this plugin doesn't support PHP files.
What can I do?

Comment: Which HTML5 tags aren't getting properly highlighted?

Comment: @Jay: All HTML5-Tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim may not be detecting that there is HTML inside of your PHP file. Have you tried manually setting the filetype?

`:set ft=html.php`

Comment: Thank you very much!! Can I set this option for all *.php-files?

Comment: I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008575/vim-activiting-html-snippets-on-php-files But the auto-indent doesn't work? What can I do?

Comment: Try:

`:filetype plugin indent on`

Comment: That option is set in my vimrc-file yet. But if I open php-files, this function doesn't work. In html-files that works great. What's the problem?

Comment: The php-code indented automaticly, but the html-code doesn't auto-indent.

Comment: It's very easy: Use **this plugin**: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=604 The html-code **and** the html-code indented.

Comment: Here's an updated version of that plugin: https://github.com/StanAngeloff/php.vim

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=html5&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search

There is the HTML5 Syntax File.

Comment: How I can integrate that file? In my syntax-folder is a file named html.vim yet. What can I do?

Comment: `copy syntax/html.vim to ~/.vim/syntax`

Comment: Thank you. It works, but if I try to edit a php-file with root-rights, the Html5-Tags not marked. The auto-indent doesn't work also with root.

Comment: As romainl said ...
I would be glad, if you gave me a vote and a "tick", if could help you :-)

Comment: @romainl. When I try that, no syntax is highlighted.

Comment: @linuscl, `sudo -e` makes a temporary copy of the file and edits it with Vim and your config just like if it was owned by you.

Comment: I know. If I get `sudo -e` the editor vi open. NOT vim. Thats the problem. So the syntax isn't highlited.